# Unity пускание луча не срабатывает

Tags: unity3d

Застрял на 3 главе книги Unity в действии. Ввожу такой же точно код как у автора книги. Но сферы появляются в месте нахождения камеры, а не в месте попадания луча. Такое ощущение что луч вообще не создаётся.

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
   {  
    Vector3 point = new Vector3(_camera.pixelWidth /2, _camera.pixelHeight /2, 0);  
    Ray ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(point); 
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) 
    { StartCoroutine(SphereIndicator(hit.point)); 
    }
```

Comment: у Вас случайно Камера не внутри коллайдера?

Comment: Всё так, автор книги чётко дал понять что камеру нужно присоединить к "игроку", а скрипт RayShooter к камере.

Comment: Есть коллайдер Player, ему подчинённый объект MainCamera. Скрин по ссылке https://drive.google.com/open?id=1D8HIulA7dsd9OkZtxRLhnHst1O44j2GP

Comment: @покажите лучше скрин из окна сцены

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J4SPih6_HrYQ4lsBYl-ggU5TxzZu3-Ck

Comment: Большое вам спасибо! Скрин из окна сцены натолкнул меня на мысль что шары упираются в колайдер игрока, так и есть. Сдвинукл камеру выше и заработало.)) Спасибо!"!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего У Вас луч упирается в коллайдер игрока. Откройте окно сцены и посмотрите внимательно не расположена ли камера(точка откуда вы пускаете луч) внутри коллайдера.

Если это так, то в unity предусмотрен специальный механизм, слой `Ignore raycast`, если вы его поставите для объекта с коллайдером, то луч находить их не будет

[image: inspector]

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо! Я уже сам увидел после того как выслал Вам скрин сцены, но про Layer Ignore RayCast вообще не знал. Ещё раз огромное спасибо!.